# Install a theme in Joomla3

Tags: php, joomla

I'm installing a theme I bought on **templatemonster** and I got this error, can anyone help me how to sort this out? Thanks.

Regards

Error #1:

> Warning: require_once(/home/sintrali/public_html/tmp/install_536c0a82c9c3c/theme1329DSinstaller/RokInstallerEvents.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sintrali/public_html/tmp/install_536c0a82c9c3c/theme1329/install.script.php on line 163

Error #2:

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/sintrali/public_html/tmp/install_536c0a82c9c3c/theme1329DSinstaller/RokInstallerEvents.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php53/lib/php') in /home/sintrali/public_html/tmp/install_536c0a82c9c3c/theme1329/install.script.php on line 163

Comment: If you have paid for the theme then why don't you ask to the support of templatemonster

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the template. You should contact your host and get them to fix the problems

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a permissions error. Try running this to fix that up, then try re-installing.

```
chmod -R 777 /home/sintrali/public_html/tmp/install_536c0a82c9c3c/theme1329
```

Comment: But every time I re-installing the system creates a new folrder tmp/install_xxxxxxxx/theme1329